# wiremock equivalent for websockets?

Tags: websocket, mocking, wiremock

I have used wiremock for testing http calls, but my current work requires websockets and I was wondering if anyone has found/used a library for standing up a localhost that will create a websocket connection that you can mock responses.

I have googled it but nothing seems to be a stand alone server, but yet just libraries that require you to add to the project. This will not work as I'm looking for something I can test across all mobile platforms/desktops.

Comment: Did you find anything for this?

Comment: I haven’t but the only answer seems intriguing. I haven’t had time to stand it up and check it out yet, but seems to be the best bet.

Comment: Hi @Randy do you have some solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is also done in Java or not, but if you can use Node or run it in a container, take a look at https://github.com/thoov/mock-socket

Answer (score 0):

See the answer on this question [Stub WebSocket server in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587248/stub-websocket-server-in-java)
There the project https://stubby4j.com/ is referenced which allows stubbing of WebSocket connections.